# What is the goal symbol that looks like a book?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

In Dead by Daylight, sometimes a symbol that looks like a book will be shown in the goal area, next to where the Generator symbol and the number of remaining generators you need to open the gate.

What does this symbol mean?

[image: Dead By Daaylight Book icon]

Comment: you have a picture?

Comment: @Dragonrage I'll have to play the game again.  The thing is, it doesn't appear to everyone on the server and it's only there sometimes.

Comment: @Dragonrage I added a picture.  It may only appear if you're the last person alive.  Also, I know from talking with someone else that spectators may or may not see it even when spectating the same player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trapdoor is placed semi-randomly on the map.  It opens when you're the last person alive.

That symbol appears when the trapdoor is open and you can escape using it.

Edit: As of the game's final release, a new requirement is also in place:  At least two generators must be powered before the trapdoor will open.

You can also open the trapdoor early if you have the very rare Skeleton Key item.  This item may only be obtainable through the Bloodweb.

Comment: On a side note, as a survivor you can hear a howling sound when you're near the trapdoor.  As the killer, you can see a square outline of the trapdoor once it opens.

Comment: if i remember correctly (and it was only two days ago) the killer can also hear the sound. I remember hearing the trapdoor but not seeing it. However i was searching for last survivor